# Difference between "an application instance" and "instance of an application"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "an application instance" and "instance of an application"? When we prefer the two words version and when the "of" version?

Comment: What's the context? Are you talking about a computer application or a job application (or something else)?

Comment: Grammatically there is not a difference.  As a tech writer, I would probably use "instance of an application" when describing the standing up process or conditions and "application instance" when describing the application itself.  For example, "When standing up an instance of the application ensure Docker is ready" versus "The application instance is specific to a tenant and so menu items may be different."

Comment: I'm talking about a computer application.

Comment: @Val Thank you!

Comment: @Val,
Could I ask one more question, please?
In which section of a grammar book I can find more information about grammatical rules for differentiation between the two version ?

Comment: @Guest provided in answer

Answer (score 0):

"An application instance" is using a noun as an adjective.  In this situation 'application' is being used as an attributive noun.  Application is an attribute of the instance.  The 'application instance' in comparison to the 'container instance'.  Here is an article I found that I think described it well.
https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html

"Instance of an application" is using the preposition 'of' to show the possesive relationship between the two nouns.  The 'instance' is just one of many for the 'application'.  This article was the best I could find.
https://www.learngrammar.net/english-grammar/use-of-prepositions-of-about-for-with-by